# Why doesn't xpath work when processing an XHTML document with lxml (in python)?

Tags: python, xml, xhtml, xpath, lxml

I am testing against the following test document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
        <title>hi there</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img class="foo" src="bar.png"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I parse the document using lxml.html, I can get the IMG with an xpath just fine:

```
>>> root = lxml.html.fromstring(doc)
>>> root.xpath("//img")
[<Element img at 1879e30>]
```

However, if I parse the document as XML and try to get the IMG tag, I get an empty result:

```
>>> tree = etree.parse(StringIO(doc))
>>> tree.getroot().xpath("//img")
[]
```

I can navigate to the element directly:

```
>>> tree.getroot().getchildren()[1].getchildren()[0]
<Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}img at f56810>
```

But of course that doesn't help me process arbitrary documents.  I would also expect to be able to query etree to get an xpath expression that will directly identify this element, which, technically I can do:

```
>>> tree.getpath(tree.getroot().getchildren()[1].getchildren()[0])
'/*/*[2]/*'
>>> tree.getroot().xpath('/*/*[2]/*')
[<Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}img at fa1750>]
```

But that xpath is, again, obviously not useful for parsing arbitrary documents.

Obviously I am missing some key issue here, but I don't know what it is.  My best guess is that it has something to do with namespaces but the only namespace defined is the default and I don't know what else I might need to consider in regards to namespaces.

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is the namespaces.  When parsed as XML, the img tag is in the http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml namespace since that is the default namespace for the  element.  You are asking for the img tag in no namespace.

Try this:

```
>>> tree.getroot().xpath(
...     "//xhtml:img", 
...     namespaces={'xhtml':'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'}
...     )
[<Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}img at 11a29e0>]
```

Comment: Quoting from http://codespeak.net/lxml/xpathxslt.html

<<Optionally, you can provide a namespaces keyword argument, which should be a dictionary mapping the namespace prefixes used in the XPath expression to namespace URIs>>

Comment: If you want to search with compact xpath expressions in the default namespace of the root element, you can use a trick that works for xhtml or other schemas, something like: `nsmap = {'h': tree.getroot().nsmap[None]}; elem.xpath('//h:img', namespaces=nsmap` — that makes it easy to write the query compactly.

Answer (score 7):

[XPath considers all unprefixed names to be in "no namespace"](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#node-tests).

In particular the spec says:

"A QName in the node test is expanded into an expanded-name using the namespace declarations from the expression context. This is the same way expansion is done for element type names in start and end-tags except that the default namespace declared with xmlns is not used: if the QName does not have a prefix, then the namespace URI is null (this is the same way attribute names are expanded). "

See those two detailed explanations of the problem and its solution: [**here**](http://www.topxml.com/people/bosley/defaultns.asp) and [**here**](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=1455253&SiteID=1). The solution is to associate a prefix (with the API that's being used) and to use it to prefix any unprefixed name in the XPath expression.

Hope this helped.

Cheers,

Dimitre Novatchev

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use tags from a single namespace only, as I see it the case above, you are much better off using lxml.objectify.

In your case it would be like

```
from lxml import objectify
root = objectify.parse(url) #also available: fromstring
```

You can access the nodes as

```
root.html
body = root.html.body
for img in body.img: #Assuming all images are within the body tag
```

While it might not be of great help in html, it can be highly useful in well structured xml.

For more info, check out http://lxml.de/objectify.html